# Is it legal to cast array of wrapper structs containing POD to the array of POD type it contains?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, casting

Is this C++ code valid or undefined behaviour? The idea is to be able to wrap a POD you have no control over into another struct to provide helper functions but still be able to use it as if it was the original POD.

```
struct Data
{
  ...//POD
};
struct Wrapper
{
  Data data;//contains only this
  void HelperFuncA();
  void HelperFuncB();
  ...//only member functions
};

...
//is this legal?
std::vector<Wrapper> vec_of_wrappers;
Data* array_of_data = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(vec_of_wrappers.data());
```

Comment: No, this is not valid. Never treat arrays polymorphically.

Comment: That's definitely illegal.  How can you be sure that the compiler won't add some padding to objects of type `Wrapper` (or, indeed, that `Data` comes at the beginning)?

Comment: If it were `vec_of_wrappers(1)`, then it could be valid on some system, otherwise `data()` is just `nullptr`

Comment: @PaulSanders there is never padding before the first element, it is guaranteed by standard. The code is illegal for other reasons (see my answer)

Comment: `Data* array_of_data = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(vec_of_wrappers.data());` is the start of Undefined Behaviour (you would need to dereference `array_of_data` for actuals UB) as none of the allowed conversions for [reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) are present in the above code. See the __Type aliasing__ section in the above link.

Comment: You don't need member functions to operate on a POD. What's wrong with `void HelperFuncA(Data* d)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now, this code is not valid. There are several reasons for this. First, casting a pointer to the first member of the struct to the struct itself violates strict aliasing rule. This you can fix by making `Wrapper` a child class of the `Data`.

The second issue is more problematic, as you are trying to treat an array (vector in this case) polymorphically. `sizeof Data` is different from the `sizeof Wrapper`, so an attempt to index an array of `Wrapper` elements as if it was an array of `Data` elements will end up pointing into random areas of the array.

Comment: Is `sizeof Data` same as the `sizeof Wrapper` without virtual functions?

Comment: "First, casting a pointer to the first member of the struct to the struct itself violates strict aliasing rule" [Not really](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4.3).

Comment: but pointer to C struct has same value with  its first member one

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. he mean class may be

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yes, but still no: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11 there is no exception here for interchangeable pointers.

Comment: "Yes", no "no". One does not access X through an Y lvalue. One accesses Y through an Y lvalue, obtained by casting a pointer to X to a pointer to Y.