# Cast array of wrapper structs to SIMD vector

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, simd, intrinsics

Say I have a wrapper struct, serving as a phantom type.

```
struct Wrapper {
  float value;
}
```

Is it legal to load an array of this struct directly into an SIMD intrinsic type such as `__m256`? For example,

```
alignas(32) Wrapper arr[8] = {};
static_assert(sizeof(Wrapper) == sizeof(float));
__m256 x = _mm256_load_ps(reinterpret_cast<float*>(arr));


// or (I think this is equivalent):
__m256 y = *(__m256 *)arr;
```

**Discussion**:

- I know that I can't *normally* [use an array of `Wrapper` like an array of `T`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69903891/431033) because the pointer arithmetic is illegal: [[expr.add]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#6).

  - Even if I can ensure the object representation is identical on the given platform (e.g. no padding in Wrapper), it would still be undefined behavior, as [described by Timur Doumler](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1912r1.pdf).
- That said, a load doesn't seem to use pointer arithmetic.
- [`__m256` is defined such that it can alias anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52117639/431033) and it seems intended that one can load, for example, `int16_t[]` into `__m256i` by casting.
- Casting a `Wrapper*` to a `float*` and taking the value does not violate strict aliasing, because of [pointer-interconvertibilty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383187/is-it-a-strict-aliasing-violation-to-alias-a-struct-as-its-first-member), though this seems irrelevant because only the final cast to `__m256*` really matters.

To me it seems like the pointer arithmetic rules don't apply: if I can assert that the types are compatible (e.g. there is no padding), then it's valid to cast directly because of the special properties of the vector type. But I haven't seen this particular usage and have some worries that a compiler might invoke the pointer arithmetic or another rule for the load operation and trigger UB. Given that this is a non-standard extension, can I be sure?

Comment: As long as `sizeof(Wrapper) == sizeof(float)` there is no UB there. Because`_m256` can alias anything so it can also alias a `Wrapper[]` and the layout of that is such that it matches what AVR expects. But why not define Wrapper as `align(32) float values[8]` or even better `template <std::size_t N> Wrapper { align(32) float values[N]; };`?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Why would you want to bake a specific SIMD width into the data structure the rest of your program is going to be touching?

Comment: @PeterCordes because the alignment gives you some percentage points improvement. What bakes the width into your code is using `_m256` and `_mm256_load_ps`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: The code in the question already uses `alignas(32)` on the array of `Wrapper arr[]`.  You should still do that, but I was assuming you'd want this for an arbitrary-sized array of structs.  In that case it would be inconvenient to access the overall `i`th element, like you'd need `arr[i/8].values[i%8]`.  But yeah if your use-case is equally convenient, putting the array inside the struct is fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes Having to add `alignas` every time you use the wrapper is tedious, that's why I suggested adding the alignment to the wrapper itself. And as you write `arr[i/8].values[i%8]` is tedious which is why I think the template is even better. Make the wrapper a single 32 byte aligned block of floats of whatever size is needed. It will add padding to the next multiple of 32.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### This is fully safe

You're not directly dereffing the `float*`, only passing it to `_mm256_load_ps` which does an aliasing-safe load.  In terms of language-lawyering, you can look at `_mm256_load_ps` / `_mm256_store_ps` as doing a `memcpy` (to a private local variable), except it's UB if the pointer isn't 32-byte aligned.

Interconvertibility between `Wrapper*` and `float*` isn't really relevant; you're not derefing a `float*`.

If you'd been using `_mm_load_ss(arr)` on a buggy GCC version that implements it as `_mm_set_ss( *ptr )` instead using a `may_alias` typdef for `float`, then that would matter.  (Unfortunately even current GCC [still has that bug](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/020b7d98589bbc928b5a66b1ed56b42af8791355/gcc/config/i386/xmmintrin.h#L903); `_mm_loadu_si32` was [fixed in GCC11.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99754) but not the older `_ss` and `_sd` loads.)  But that *is* a compiler bug, IMO.  `_mm_load_ps` is aliasing-safe, so it makes no sense that `_mm_load_ss` wouldn't be, when they both take `float*`.  If you wanted a load with normal C aliasing/alignment semantics to promise more to the optimizer, you'd just deref yourself, using `_mm_set_ss( *foo )`.

---

The exact aliasing semantics of Intel Intrinsics are not AFAIK documented anywhere.  A lot of x86-specific code has been developed with MSVC, which doesn't enforce strict aliasing at all, i.e. it's like `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing`, defining the behaviour of stuff like `*(int*)my_float` and even encouraging it for type-punning.

Not sure about Intel's compiler historically, but I'm guessing it also didn't do type-based aliasing optimizations, otherwise they hopefully would have defined better intrinsics for `movd` 32-bit integer loads/stores much earlier than `_mm_loadu_si32` in the last few years.  You can tell from the `void*` arg that it's recent: Intel previously did insane stuff like `_mm_loadl_epi64(__m128i*)` for a `movq` load, taking a pointer to a 16-byte object but only loading the low 8 bytes (with no alignment requirement).

So a lot of Intel intrinsics stuff seemed pretty casual about C and C++ safety rules, like it was designed by people who thought of C as a portable assembler.  Or at least that their intrinsics were supposed to work that way.

---

As I pointed out in my answer you linked in the question ([Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond/52117639#52117639)), Intel's intrinsics API effectively requires compilers to support creating misaligned pointers as long as you don't deref them yourself.  Including misaligned `float*` for `_mm_loadu_ps`, which supports *any* alignment, not just multiples of 4.

You could probably argue that supporting Intel's intrinsics API (in a way that's compatible with the examples Intel's published) might not require supporting arbitrary casting between pointer types (without deref), but in practice all x86 compilers do, because they target a flat memory model with byte-addressable memory.

With the existence of intrinsics for gather and scatter, use-cases like using a `0` base with pointer elements for `_mm256_i64gather_epi64` (e.g. to walk 4 linked lists in parallel) require that a C++ implementation use a sane object-representation for pointers if they want to support that.

As usual with Intel intrinsics, I don't think there's documentation that 100% nails down proof that it would be safe to use `_mm_load_ps` on a `struct { int a; float b[3]; };`, but I think everyone working with intrinsics expects that to be the case.  And nobody would want to use a compiler that broke it for a cases where `memcpy` with the same source pointer would be safe.

But in your case, you don't even need to depend on any de-facto guarantees here, beyond the fact that `_mm256_load_ps` itself is an aliasing-safe load.  **You've correctly shown that it's 100% safe to create that `float*` in ISO C, and pass it to an opaque function.**

---

**And yes, deref of an `__m256*` is exactly equivalent to `_mm256_load_ps`**, and is in fact how most compilers implement `_mm256_load_ps`.

(By comparison, `_mm256_loadu_ps` would cast to a pointer to a less-aligned 32-byte vector type which isn't part of the documented API, like GCC's `__m256_u*`.  Or maybe pass it to a builtin function. But however the compiler makes it happen, it's equivalent to a memcpy, including the lack of alignment requirement.)